# Сравнение значений массива Java

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив, в нем `n` чисел (как дробных, так и целых). Стоит задача сравнить значения массива, и при совпадении — вывести на экран\записать в файл.

Конкретно это используется в скрипте, который обеспечивает отображение действующих остатков на сайте при загрузке информации, сравниваются два массива (тот, который есть, и новый), и те значения, которые совпали, выводятся. К примеру, `х = 1` и `у = 1`.

Как сделать так, чтобы если эти значения равны, то происходило действие (запись в файл, вывод и т.д.)? Как можно проверить значения на совпадение?

Comment: `==` для примитивов и `.equals(...)` для объектов.

Comment: `сравнить значения массива` – с каким-то одним числом? Друг с другом?

Comment: @Zvezd Вы сами хоть пробовали решить задачу самостоятельно?

Comment: друг с другом,
я пробовал сам, но у меня не получается сравнить их между собой, и найти совпадения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я понял суть задания, то вот:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < list.length; i2++){
        if(i2 == i) continue;
        if(list[i2] == list[i]){

            /* если совпало */

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Этот вариант выводит совпадение только один раз

```
ArrayList<Float> found = new ArrayList<Float>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < list.length; i2++){
        if(i2 == i) continue;
        if(list[i2] == list[i]){
            if(found.contains(list[i])) continue;
            found.add(list[i]);

            /* если совпало */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: проще тогда уж сделать цикл `for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)`. и сравнивать так `if(list[i-1] == list[i])`

Comment: Если я Вас понял, то Ваш цикл сравнивает попарно, но если одно значение в начале, а другое в конце, то он не выдаст, что были совпадения. Проверено на этом массиве: `float[] list = {1, 2.5F, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 2.5F}`

Comment: я, почему то, предположил что массив заранее отсортирован)

Comment: Впринцыпе вариант неплохой, но он если все элементы массива одинаковы, то идет дублирование вывода (например 3 значения выводятся 9 раз),

Comment: Можно добавить массив для уже найденых элементов и если совпало первый раз, элемент добавлять, если совпадение уже было - пропускать.

Comment: Обновил первый пост для информативности, предложенный Вами вариант пробовал выводится только одно совпадение, а нужно что бы выводились все. К примеру числа 3 3 3 2 1 1 - выводятся 3 3 3 1 1, или 3 3 1 - выводятся 3 3

Comment: @Zvezd , Для Вас в таком случае подойдёт первый вариант (проверено на ваших примерах).

Comment: Он подойдет для тех данных где есть хотя бы 1 отличный компонент, например 3 3 1, если введено 3 3 3, происходит дубляж

Answer (score -4):

Можно использовать такой цикл...

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] = list[i]) {
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
    else {
        list[i]++
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш пример выведет все елементы массива

Comment: @Victor, Он просто не скомпилируется.

Comment: Василий, а вас не смущает условие `list[i]=list[i]`?